# Get month-wise data in SQL Server Query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am trying to get data month wise for that I have created query but have some repeated record in my result as shown below using SQL Server.

```
SELECT DM.deptdesc, 
   PIM.itemcode, 
   PIM.itemdesc, 
   Isnull(Sum(IM.issuedqty), 0) AS 'Issued', 
   Datename(month, IM.dt)       AS MONTH, 
   Year(IM.dt)                  AS year 
FROM  poitemmaster AS PIM 
   inner JOIN issuematerial AS IM 
                ON PIM.itemcode = IM.itemcode 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN departmentmaster AS DM 
                ON PIM.deptcode = DM.deptcode 
WHERE  PIM.itemcode = 'ICMEL00001' 
GROUP  BY DM.deptdesc, 
      PIM.itemcode, 
      PIM.itemdesc, 
      IM.issuedqty, 
      Datename(month, IM.dt), 
      Year(IM.dt)
```

My query return this data

[image: query default return data]

but I want to like this

[image: Actual I want to like this]

I want the month-wise sum in quantity. What should I have to do for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the issuedqty column from the group by, and add a SUM() to the same column in the column list

```
SELECT DM.deptdesc, 
   PIM.itemcode, 
   PIM.itemdesc, 
   Sum(ISNULL(IM.issuedqty, 0) AS 'Issued', 
   Datename(month, IM.dt)       AS MONTH, 
   Year(IM.dt)                  AS year 
FROM  poitemmaster AS PIM 
   inner JOIN issuematerial AS IM 
                ON PIM.itemcode = IM.itemcode 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN departmentmaster AS DM 
                ON PIM.deptcode = DM.deptcode 
WHERE  PIM.itemcode = 'ICMEL00001' 
GROUP  BY DM.deptdesc, 
      PIM.itemcode, 
      PIM.itemdesc, 
      Datename(month, IM.dt), 
      Year(IM.dt)
```